# Do we really want to eliminate questions about Readers that are also tablets?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

We have had a few questions [(1)](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/623/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-manage-an-overheated-device) [(2)](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/633/how-can-i-remove-apps-from-my-cloud?noredirect=1#comment772_633) where people have wanted to close the questions because the devices are not purely e-readers.

Our help center states:

> Ebooks Stack Exchange is for ebook publishers and readers.

If we are going to exclude tablet questions, especially if we are going to label the Nook HD , Nook Color, and the Kindle Fire as tablets not ereaders, we should update the help center to exclude this.

So should we exclude questions about the standard use of these Tablet Readers?

Comment: While I agree with your basic idea that we may be limitting our scope to the point of no site.  Your question as currently written looks like a dupe to http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/147/should-kinde-fire-questions-not-about-reading-ebooks-be-off-topic

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I would agree had that question actually dealt with the general question... instead it dealt with the specific question that spurred the meta question.  I would like this question to specifically address the general topic.

Answer (score 6):

I have a slightly different suggestion (more nuanced).

- Question about generic functionality of a tablet **that has possible realistic bearing on reading ebooks** should be on-topic.

  Examples:

  - Deleting a file (can be relevant to book reading, as I can personally attest to).
  - Overheating device while charging. (many people charge while reading).
- Questions about generic functionality that **has no clear or explicit bearing on reading ebooks** should be off-topic

  Examples:

  - Overheating when running a random program (partially because, to the best of my knowledge, a device that isn't broken does NOT heat up from ebook reading - only from graphics intensive things like games or video).

    *Side note - if the ellipsed assuption above is proven false, I would be happy to shift that example into ontopic - it's all about the reasoning and not specific examples.*
  - Generic app management (unless asked about specific ebook reading app).

    As a note, Kinle Fire app management question should simply be migrated to Android.SE where it's ontopic

Comment: Why should we limit it?  I see no harm in having a few questions asking to support the reader... if you do not like them just downvote or ignore them

Comment: @Chad - you can say the same about ANY off-topic topics on ANY SE site.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an unnecessary limiting of the stie.

Questions about the basic use of common tablets that are used by many as primarily ereaders should be on topic.

Closing questions like these are more likely to drive people away from our site for no good reason.  I agree we should not be answering questions about use of non-reader apps, but questions about the basic functionality, like deleting files and overheating of the device, should be on topic and welcomed at the site.

Let us not become so intolarant and snipey about questions that we drive users away.  That is a recipe to seeing this site closed.

Comment: I'm generally in the "don't close stuff" camp overall, but "overheating" is typically VERY correlated with gaming and not ebook reading. So I would say overheating one is off-topic, no matter how you slice it. Deleting files may relate to ebooks, so that one can be in-scope if you squint hard enough :)

Comment: @DVK - Even so how does that generalized question hurt the SE by being here?  What about the person who has a ereader that overheats even when they are reading books?

Comment: if you find me an example of that happening with non-broken device, i'll eat crow and publically acknowledge that this question was ontopic.

Comment: charging heating a device is different... THAT question, I would support as ontopic (and actually have an answer for :)

Comment: @DVK - That dodges my question about what harm does that generalized question do to the SE by being allowed?

Comment: harm is that the question turns this site into "support my generic gadget" site.

Comment: @DVK  then you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DVK What does your example of charging have to do with using the device for reading eBooks, then?  It's really the same difference.  If general hardware/power/etc. issues are on-topic, then why should we be so selective.  I'm using an eReader device exactly as the manufacturer prescribes, no modifications.  For the record, it does get hot with larger eBooks laden with lots of images.

Comment: @jonsca - for both your points, see my asnswer

Comment: @dvk You don't really cover it, your connection with "charging while reading" is a bit loose of an interpretation, I think.

Comment: @jonsca - ~30% of my reading is when charging. And my phone gets hot doing it. You have a strange definition of "loose"

Comment: @DVK So why is your phone okay but the Kindle Fire not?  "Loose" is that you are a bit subjective about your rules, basing them on what you have experienced.

Comment: @jonsca - Kindle fire being heated getting charged is as OK and on-topic as my phone. Read carefully before getting confrontational.

Comment: @DVK I did read quite carefully, you are saying that because you use your phone as an eBook reader, questions it about overheating while charging would be on-topic.

Comment: @jonsca - Many people read while their device charges. It's a common pattern (continuous LCD use drains battery; and people read in bed before sleep when plugged in). That makes it relevant to ebooks.

Comment: `Questions about generic functionality that has no clear or explicit bearing on reading ebooks should be off-topic` should pertain to charging just as much as overheating while using the device for an intended purpose.

Comment: I disagree, but I don't think we're going to get any further.  Let's see how the community reacts.